# Unable to spawn a p3at in gazebo

Tags: ros, p3at

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using; 1. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS/ROS indigo/ Gazebo/p3at as robot

I wish to spawn my p3at into gazebosim.
my launch file is following;

```
<launch>

<!--##########################################################################-->
<!--Launching gazebo world --> 
<arg name="world"  default="my_world"/>
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
<arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
<arg name="debug" value="false"/>
<arg name="gui" value="true" />
<arg name="world_name" value="$(find scca)/worlds/$(arg world).world"/>
</include>
<!--##########################################################################-->
<!-- Spawn a robot into Gazebo -->
<node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-file $(find p3at_description)/urdf/p3at1.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model P3AT" />
<!--##########################################################################-->

<!--##########################################################################-->
</launch>
```

it is not throwing any error message, but unable to spawn p3at in gazebo.

**EDIT-1:**

If i run urdf separately i.e. scca.launch as;

```
<launch>

<!--##########################################################################-->
<!--Launching gazebo world --> 
<arg name="world"  default="my_world"/>
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
<arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
<arg name="debug" value="false"/>
<arg name="gui" value="true" />
<arg name="world_name" value="$(find scca)/worlds/$(arg world).world"/>
</include>
</launch>
```

and urdf file as;

```
rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file `rospack find p3at_description`/urdf/p3at1.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model p3at
```

it gives a success message, as;

```
spawn_model script started
[INFO] [WallTime: 1473777604.025414] [0.000000] Loading model xml from file
[INFO] [WallTime: 1473777604.025924] [0.000000] Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[INFO] [WallTime: 1473777604.028502] [0.000000] Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[INFO] [WallTime: 1473777604.125985] [7418.063000] Spawn status: SpawnModel: Successfully spawned model
bcr-lab@bcrlab-HP-Z800-Workstation:~$
```

but unable to spawn p3at in gazebo.

**EDIT-2**
One warning appears;
[image: image description]

and here is rqt graph
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243686/unable-to-spawn-a-p3at-in-gazebo/) by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the isssue , and now i can spawn the same, here is my launch file,

```
<launch>

<!--##########################################################################-->
<!-- these are the arguments you can pass this launch file, for example paused:=true -->
<arg name="paused" default="false"/>
<arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
<arg name="gui" default="true"/>
<arg name="headless" default="false"/>
<arg name="debug" default="false"/>
<!--##########################################################################-->
<!--Launching gazebo world -->
<arg name="world"  default="my_world"/>
 <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
 <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
 <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
 <arg name="gui" value="true" />
 <arg name="world_name" value="$(find scca)/worlds/$(arg world).world"/>
 </include>
<!--##########################################################################-->
<arg name="urdf" default="$(find p3at_description)/urdf/pioneer3dx.xacro" />
<arg name="name" default="pioneer3at" />
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(arg urdf)" />
<node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model $(arg name)" />
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />
<!--##########################################################################-->
 </launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) with karma: 77 on 2016-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0